# How do I animate inserting/deleting an item with ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I know I can animate inserting/deleting items easily with AnimatedList, but I need my users to be able to reorder the list so I am using ReorderableListView. But now it looks really bad when a user is inserting an item and suddenly the item is on the list. Same for the delete action. How can I solve it?